# Finding inorder successor in a 2-3 Tree

Tags: binary-search-tree, pseudocode

I was trying to work on a pseudo code for finding a inorder successor in a 2-3 Tree.
However, My work was way too messy - including too many if statements.

I would love to see an efficient pseudo code for such task if possible :)

Comment: [Please paste your code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). And I guess this question may belong to [codereview.SE]

Comment: @snipsnipsnip Please don't suggest users post pseudo-code on CR because it is not [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as it [would lead to poor reviews](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709/120114)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. Is this question on-topic on SO given enough detail is added?